# Boundary condition from extremization

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, variational-principle, holographic-principle

I have an AdS Schwarzschild blackhole spacetime where the metric is given by,

$$ds^2 = \frac{1}{z^2} \left( -f(z) dt^2 + \frac{dz^2}{f(z)} + dx^2 \right) \tag{1}\label{1}$$

There is a plane embedded in this spacetime given by the equation $t=x$ and is shown as a red plane in the image below. My goal is to find the extremal curve (blue color) in the spacetime starting at $(t_i,z_i,x_i) = (0,\epsilon,0)$ up to $(t_f,z_f,x_f) = (t_*,z_*,x_*)$. If the red plane is perpendicular to the x-axis given by the equation $x=0$ then obviously the blue curve ends on the red plane orthogonally (of course in a Lorentzian sense) but in this case, the plane is tilted.

The metric is static and has time-independent metric components so the bulk spacetime is static so $t'(x) = 0$ all the way.

The area functional is given by,

$$A = \int_0^{x_*} \frac{dx}{z^3} \sqrt{-f(z) t'^2 + \frac{z'^2}{f(z)} + 1} \tag{2}\label{2}$$

To determine the boundary contribution, we can do the variation,

\begin{align}
\delta A & = \int_0^{x_*} \frac{dx}{z^3} \left( \frac{-f(z) t' \delta t'}{\sqrt{-f(z) t'^2 + \frac{z'^2}{f(z)} + 1}} + \frac{z' \delta z'}{ f(z)\sqrt{-f(z) t'^2 + \frac{z'^2}{f(z)} + 1}}\right) + \int_0^{x_*} dx \frac{\delta A}{\delta y_i} \delta y_i\\
 & = \frac{1}{z^3} \left( \frac{-f(z) t' \delta t}{\sqrt{-f(z) t'^2 + \frac{z'^2}{f(z)} + 1}} + \frac{z' \delta z}{ f(z)\sqrt{-f(z) t'^2 + \frac{z'^2}{f(z)} + 1}}\right) \bigg\rvert^{x_*}_{0,\epsilon} + \int_0^{x_*} dx (\rm{EOM})_i \delta y_i
\end{align}

In the last time, integration by parts has been done to get the boundary term. In order for it to vanish, we have (I only evaluate the upper limit since that is where my question lies)

$$-f(z_*) t'(x_*) \delta t +  z'(x_*) \delta z = 0$$

The metric both satisfy $t \rightarrow -t$ and $x \rightarrow -x$ so the extremal curve should be symmetric along the $x$ and $t$ direction all the way.

Given all these, how can I determine the values of $t'_*$ and $z'_*$?

[image]